# How to define a class of a parameter that is not present in the select?

Tags: parameters, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I got a problem with the Jasper Studio application. I want to make a parameter, but I don't find `java.lang.collection` in the class select.

What's the solution so that java.lang.collection is in the application

[image: Selects]

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options

1. Type the class directly (it's an select, but you can also type)
2. Press the button next to the select it will open a Dialog as shown in image, then type your class and press "OK"

[image: Open type]

I'm not sure what class `java.lang.collection` is I guess your are looking for [`java.util.Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)